# Resize Multiple Images

Tags: image, scripting, paint

I need to resize a lot of jpeg images from the original to 220x160 for a website.

I'm currently just opening in paint and resizing them manually, then adding -w to the end of the filename.

Note that we are not resizing them using html on the website itself because it's slowing down the website.

Is there a way to resize e.g. 10+ images to 220x160 and append -w to all the filenames without doing it manually, and without using software that I must buy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with ImageMagick which is free and available for Windows and Linux and OSX [here](http://www.imagemagick.org).

To do a single image, you would type the following into the Command Prompt in Windows:

```
convert input.jpg -resize 220x160! input_w.jpg
```

I can probably work out how to do it in a loop, if you wait a while, or someone else may tell me the `FOR` syntax for Windows...

Ok, Windows isn't my thing, but something like this to make all the smaller images and save them into a subdirectory called `SMALL`

```
MKDIR SMALL
FOR %x in (*.jpg) DO convert %x -resize 220x160! SMALL\%~nx_w.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Irfanview is free and has command line processing which you can use in a batch file.